# can a word be both an object and a subject in a clause?

Tags: subjects, objects

> She handed him a cup of tea **that** he knew without tasting would be exactly as he liked it.

Is "that" the object of "he knew" and the subject of "would be…"?

In other words, is this clause conveying the same meaning as "He knew that the tea would be exactly as he liked it"?

Comment: Out of politeness, don't you think you should at least acknowledge the two answers you have been given?

Comment: @BillJ I'm sorry, it seems that two of you have given different answers, you suggested that "that" is a clause subordinator, and the other claimed "that" is a relative pronoun. I don't know which one is right! And I am still confused

Comment: If I get time, I'll post a tree diagram on my answer, which should make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *She handed him a cup of tea that he knew without tasting* [ ___ *would be*
> *exactly as he liked it*].

If it's intended to convey the meaning you suggest, then the relativised element is subject of the embedded "would" clause, as shown by the gap notation '___'. Fused head constructions aside, it is a theoretical impossibility for a constituent to have more than one function.

Incidentally, the PP "without tasting" is just an adjunct and not relevant to your question.

Note that strictly speaking "that" is not a relative pronoun but a clause subordinator with gap representing the covert position of the relativised element.

Comment: do you mean that "that" here is just a conjunction to combine the main clause and subordinate clause? In other words it doesn't refer to the tea, If I understand correctly. But the following statements you said overwhelmed me because I never heard of it. Do you have other examples that I can take as a reference to better understand "a clause subordinator with gap representing the covert position of the relativised element", or recommended grammatical books I can search？

Comment: @wonderfulwonder Yes, it introduces the relative clause but it is not actually a relative pronoun but a subordinator (your 'conjunction').  But at your level you may consider it to be one until you progress to a higher level of grammar. In which case, it is subject of the embedded _would_ clause which I bracketed in my answer. Relative clauses that contain a further subordinate clause are a little tricky to understand.

Comment: @wonderfulwonder I would analyse it differently to MarcinManhattan. The main (matrix) clause is the whole sentence.  Within the sentence the Od of "handed" is "a cup of tea that he knew without tasting would be exactly as he liked it". "Tea" is modified by the relative clause "that he knew without tasting would be exactly as he liked it". Within the relative clause is the embedded clause "would be exactly as he liked it", which has "that" (i.e. “tea”) as subject. Thus there's a clause within a clause. "Without tasting" is just an optional adjunct and not relevant here. OK now?

Comment: Can you make other kinds of sentences which have the same constructure as this so that I can compare and contrast them?

Comment: I dropped an apple that my mom gave me is expensive.  Is this one making any sense?

Comment: @wonderfulwonder You need to add another "that":  _I dropped an apple that my mom gave me **that** is expensive_.

Comment: I have new thoughts on the question. I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general a word can not function as both a subject and an object.<sup>1</sup>

In your sentence, "that" is a relative pronoun referring to "a cup of tea" (or perhaps just "tea"). Within the relative clause, it functions as a subject. I'll put it in bold type below.

The relative clause is a bit complicated because it includes what can be considered a reporting clause: "he knew without tasting". Removing it, we get:

> She handed him a cup of tea [**that** would be exactly as he liked it].

It is now clearer that "that" is the subject of the relative clause (which I've put inside brackets). If we wanted to re-write the relative clause as an independent clause, we'd get:

> **That** would be exactly as he liked it.

We can make this clause (which I'll put into brackets again) an object of the original reporting clause:

> He knew without tasting [that **that** would be exactly as he liked it].<sup>2</sup>

This is similar to the sentence that you ask about at the end of your question.

---

<sup>1</sup>There can be exceptions to this rule in some situations, but they wouldn't apply here.

<sup>2</sup>Because the clause now functions as an object, I've introduced it with the subordinating conjunction "that".

Comment: it's so complicated, I can see "that" is the subject of the clause, but I am still confused about how this sentence you gave, which is "He knew without tasting [that that would be exactly as he liked it", ends up becoming the sentence I want to ask?

Comment: @wonderfulwonder If you remove "without tasting" (which is just a modifier) and replace the second "that" with "the tea", then it becomes the sentence at the end of your question.

Comment: no, no. I'm sorry that I didn't make myself clear. The sentence I want to ask is "She handed him a cup of tea that he knew without tasting would be exactly as he liked it". Why could the second "that" be moved to the front of "he knew"?

Comment: @wonderfulwonder Sorry, I'm a little confused because that sentence has only one "that" in it. It is a relative pronoun, which introduces a relative clause. There is no reason to add a second "that". I only added another "that" (a subordinating conjunction) when I changed the clause from a relative clause into a direct object clause.

Comment: ①He knew without tasting [that(1) that(2) would be exactly as he liked it. In the origin sentence, "②She handed him a cup of tea that(2) he knew without tasting would be exactly as he liked it", the second "that" have been moved to the front of "he knew". I want to know why that is.

Comment: @wonderfulwonder Oh, I see what you mean. In the first sentence, "he knew without tasting" is the main clause, so it precedes the subordinate clause. In the second sentence, "he knew without tasting" is a reporting clause, so its position changes. If you'd like to ask about the positions of reporting clauses (which can vary), I recommend asking a new question, because I can't explain all of the details in a comment.

Comment: @wonderfulwonder The bracketing is like this:  "She handed him a cup of tea [that he knew [___ would be exactly as he liked it]]. The relativised element is subject of the embedded “would” clause. We understand that she handed him a cup of tea and this tea would be exactly as he liked it.